# Split .csv while keeping description first row

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Import module
import os

# Define file_splitter function
def file_splitter(fullfilepath, lines=50):
  """Splits a plain text file based on line count."""
    path, filename = os.path.split(fullfilepath)
    basename, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)

# Open source text file
    with open(fullfilepath, 'r') as f_in:
        try:
        # Open first output file
            f_output = os.path.join(path, '{}_{}{}'.format(basename, 0, ext))
            f_out = open(f_output, 'w')

        # Read input file one line at a time
        for i, line in enumerate(f_in):
        # When current line can be divided by the line
        # count close the output file and open the next one
            if i % lines == 0:
                f_out.close()
                f_output = os.path.join(path, '{}_{}{}'.format(basename, i, ext))
                f_out = open(f_output, 'w')

            # Write current line to output file
            f_out.write(line)

        finally:
        # Close last output file
            f_out.close()

# Call function with source text file and line count
file_splitter('Products_con_almacen_stock.csv', 12000)
```

This splits a file `Products_con_almacen_stock.csv` into chunks of 120.000 lines.

Now, every chunk has the columns and rows, but no header, only the first chunk has it, I'd like to preserve the first descriptive row on every chunk.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please consider using the [built-in CSV module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
first = True
for line in lines:
    if first: 
        header = line
        first = False
    ....
```

You can then use header in all subsequent files.

Comment: Hi, Thank You very much, it says: in file_splitter
    for line in lines:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Well, you need to adapt is recipe to your needs. The key is to have a flag to know if you are looking at the first line, and to keep this first line around for future use.